# How to convert if expression to when in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I convert the following code from `if expression` to `when` by using Kotlin?

Actually i'm using 2 adapters inside my Activity and i got problem  will converting `if expression` to `when`, any solution?

**Here is my code**

```
    var ADAPTER_TYPE_1=adapter1
    var ADAPTER_TYPE_2=adapter2

   if(ADAPTER_TYPE_1 ==lvFoods2.adapter) {
       ADAPTER_TYPE_1 = FoodAdapter(listOfFoods2, this)
       lvFoods2.adapter = ADAPTER_TYPE_1
    } else if (ADAPTER_TYPE_2==lvFoods2.adapter) {
       ADAPTER_TYPE_2 = FoodAdapter2(listOfFoods3, this)
       lvFoods2.adapter = ADAPTER_TYPE_2
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var adapterType1 = adapter1
var adapterType2 = adapter2

lvFoods2.adapter = when (lvFoods2.adapter) {
    adapterType1 -> FoodAdapter(listOfFoods2, this).also { adapterType1 = it }
    adapterType2 -> FoodAdapter2(listOfFoods3, this).also { adapterType2 = it }
    else -> lvFoods2.adapter
}
```